# findTransaction not finding tag

Tags: iri-legacy-api, optional-tag

I was experimenting with some transactions and I wonder why the node cant find a transaction when I search for it by its TAG, yet finds it when I search for it by its transaction hash.

Example:

```
curl http://iota.love:16000 \
-X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1' \
-d '{"command": "findTransactions", "tags": 
["XBBDSARBDBQBKBDBOCB9I9ABIAZ"]}'
```

for example returns

```
{"hashes":[],"duration":0}
```

while searching for the bundle hash returns me the transaction:

```
curl http://iota.love:16000 \
-X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1' \
-d '{"command": "findTransactions", "bundles":   
["UWDGKIXABHG9PSWYXBSRK9JRZH9NEAOHNDEUINWRKGIIPNKWUSZFCGTVFTPNKYSALGHRHSIVUCI9KXFEW"]}'
```

returns me the transaction

```
{"hashes":["KZBQRQQXRUPROLIPITVB9OOFVPVCCG9NWEPSOZCKWXNTZENUNTRNPVFXDUBKESFZ9BDADPQMKZDF99999"],"duration":1}
```

https://thetangle.org/transaction/KZBQRQQXRUPROLIPITVB9OOFVPVCCG9NWEPSOZCKWXNTZENUNTRNPVFXDUBKESFZ9BDADPQMKZDF99999

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the fact that a transaction has two "tag" fields. The traditional/obsolete one (called either "tag" or "obsoleteTag"), and a "new tag" which is not part of the signature.

Thetangle.org shows the new tag, while the search functions search for the old one.

So whenever the tags of a transaction differ, you won't be able to find it via the tag shown on thetangle.org.

Try `QDBDSARBDBQBKBDBOCB9I9ABIAZ` and you will find your transaction.