# findTransactionObjects() call returning empty array when searching for tag

Tags: iri-legacy-api, javascript

With this `findTransactionObjects` call:

`iota.api.findTransactionObjects({ tags: [ 'ZARCXARCQCVAZA9BUAZASCVAEXP' ]}, callback)`

I am getting back an empty array. However, when I search for the tag on thetangle.org:

https://thetangle.org/transaction/TRZASQYKGZJSQVPJUWOWPFYVZQOCPSEEFODZOZPZJWPBWEAMMYIDBVWRVMTRTQQCVEONEJRGDTABZ9999

I get back the transfer object. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is a duplicate of [findTransaction not finding tag](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/1586/212).

Comment: @RobertoGiorgetti Then please vote to close as a duplicate. As a mod, I cannot vote any more (any of my decisions are final).

Comment: @mihi You are right but I cannot flag as duplicate because indicating the other question I receive the message: "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer". Where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry @RobertoGiorgetti, you are right, the question did not have an answer at the time you tried to close it first (I wrote it later).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that a transaction has two "tag" fields. The traditional/obsolete one (called either "tag" or "obsoleteTag"), and a "new tag" (or just "tag") which is not part of the signature.

Thetangle.org shows the new tag, while the search functions search for the old one.

So whenever the tags of a transaction differ, you won't be able to find it via the tag shown on thetangle.org.

Try `CDRCXARCQCVAZA9BUAZASCVAEXP` and you will find your transaction.